# Как развернуть MySQL Server через SQLyog

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно развернуть MySQL Server. Можно ли это сделать с помощью SQLyog, не используя командную строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, установить сервер с помощью тулзы для его администрирования не получится.